# When does coordinate-wise differentiability imply $\ell^{p}$ differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lp-spaces

For $p \in [1,\infty]$, consider the sequence space $\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ consisting of real sequences $x = (x_{i})_{i =1}^{\infty}$ with norm $\lVert x \rVert_{p} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{p} \right)^{1/p}$ for $p < \infty$ and $\lVert x \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{i}|x_{i}|$.

Let $A$ be a **bounded** linear operator on $\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ for some $p$. Let $u: [0,\infty) \to \ell^{p}(\mathbb{N})$, and write $u(t) = (u_{1}(t), u_{2}(t),\dots)$. Suppose that each coordinate function $u_{i}: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, right-differentiable at $0$, and satisfies

$$u_{i}'(t) = (Au(t))_{i}$$

for all $t \geq 0$. My question: is it the case that
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\left \lVert \frac{u(t+h) - u(t)}{h} - Au(t) \right \rVert_{p} = 0$$
for all $t$? If not, is there a reasonable counterexample?

Comment: You are giving your space two topologies, once the norm topology and once the topology generated by the seminorms $x\mapsto |x_i|$. Then you want to know:
When does the equation
$$u' = Au$$
have a unique solution? In the norm topology the answer is affirmative, since its a Banach space. For the other topology its more complicated, infact you have chosen a very bad topology. If you read this review http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM1994v049n03ABEH002258 you will see that almost every condition about uniqueness of solutions requires the seminorm topology to be sequentially complete, which ...

Comment: ... fails here. The statement still has a good chance of being true (maybe even with elementary reasoning!) but the nice theorems all don't apply. If you are a little bit more restrictive with the topology, for example instead of the looking only at the component semi-norms you also take $x\mapsto |f(x)|$ for all $f\in \ell^p(\Bbb N)^*$ then you can apply the theorems and what you want is true. (Note that $u(t)=\exp(tA)u(0)$ is always a solution here, so the only question left to ask is about uniqueness)

Comment: Reminds me of the notion of "metric differentiability" in sense of Kirchheim (1994). But I dont see how to realize the linear operator A.

Comment: This seems to be a hard question. I checked the left shift $Ax=(x_{k+1})$ and for this special operator it seems to be true (by application of the Pringsheim Boas Theorem to $f=u_1$; https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlid=bams%2F1183498133) .

Comment: I think that it is possible to bound the difference quotient $\lVert \frac{u(t+h) - u(t)}{h} - Au(t) \rVert_{p}^{p}$ above by $\frac{\lVert A \rVert^{p}}{h}\int_{t}^{t+h}\lVert u(s) - u(t) \rVert_{p}^{p}\,ds$ for $h>0$. So if $u$ is continuous (as a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $\ell^{p}$), then the statement is true. But the continuity of $u$ is unclear to me.

Comment: @Austin80  Yes, in general a function $u:[0,∞)→l^p$ which is coordinatewise differentiable and even with $(u_i'(t))∈l^p$ $(t≥0)$ can be discontinuous. So continuity must follow form the differential equation. In case of the shift operator this is true but not trivial. So I guess the general case is much harder.